# undefined method 'paper_trail_event='

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I've followed the extremely simple [set up guide for the paper_trail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail).

In my class I've got

```
class MyClass
 has_paper_trail on:[:update]
```

Everything is working fine, until I decided to set my own trail events as per the paper_trail guide:

> PaperTrail supplies a custom accessor method called paper_trail_event, which it will attempt to use to fill the event field before falling back on one of the default events.

So now, in one of my model methods, I set the event like so:

```
def change_status
 self.paper_trail_event = 'status_change_event'
 self.status = 'pending'
 self.save
end
```

But when I do this I get this error:

> undefined method `paper_trail_event='

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in responses to [the GitHub issue you filed against the repo](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/223), this feature was just implemented into the master branch a few days ago, and there has not been an official release yet.  It will be available once `2.7.2` is released.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are calling on a method which does not exist. Do you have a method called paper_trail_status ?